# Do I need a LDAP Server For RICOH Scan to Email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, network-printer, scanner, ldap, multi-function-printer

We have a RICOH Aficio MP C2051 at my workplace. Our office does not have its own server or domain, and I noted that in the manual, it says we need to Set Up LDAP in order to use Scan to E-mail. Also, the scan to folder used to work, but it no longer does. Are both of these issues connected, and how can I work around the LDAP. Thank you.

P.S.: I have fed in all the other network/admin settings for the scan to email function.

Comment: We have a Xerox WorkCentre. It works with LDAP but you can manually enter an e-mail address. You should consult with your network admin to see if port 25 is blocked internally. In our environment, only servers using a specific block of IP addresses can use port 25. It is blocked everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to use LDAP.

According to this "[Scan to E-mail White Paper](http://www.tsrc.ricoh-usa.com/pwhp/Scan_to_E-mail.pdf)" by Ricoh, you can set up individual addresses manually. Have a look at the paper starting at Section 4.3 (pg 10) in that manual. Section 4.6 talks about address book management from your browser. It shows how you can add, delete and edit users manually. Section 4.7 shows how to do the same from the printer's front panel.

From the printer's web page, go to Address Book. There are buttons labelled "Add User", "Change" and "Delete" From the front panel, go to either User Tools > System Settings > Administrator Tools or User Tools > System settings > Key Operator Tools > Address Book

To set Scan-to-Folder settings from the front panel, press the Scan button, and the Folder tab. The, press Manual Entry, SMB and browse the network. Existing entries can be edited from the Folder tab. Screenshots of the sequence can be found [here.](http://www.copyplanet.eu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=87:creating-scan-to-folder-destinations-on-ricoh-mpc-2051older&catid=99&Itemid=519) Or, download the "[Scan-to Folder](http://www.tsrc.ricoh-usa.com/pwhp/Scan%20to%20Folder%20White%20Paper.pdf)" white paper. This also shows how to do it from your browser.

Comment: Thanks @hdhondt. I've done all those setting yet, when I scan, it says shows me an error, cannot send mail to this recipient. I'm not sure what the issue is. Thanks alot!

Comment: Check that all SMTP settings are correct. Some SMTP servers only accept email from recognised senders, so try setting the scanner's send-from address to your own, as that will avoid any problems there.

Comment: Hmm, I tried using my work email, didnt work, so i created a gmail account for the scanner, the SMPT there did not work as well. Im just calling it and requesting support since we have a $350 contract with RICOH. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

For a machine of this age, you're looking at a few possible problems:

**General**:

- Have you confirmed your subnet and default gateway are correct? If they're wrong/missing, you'll still be able to print (data coming in) but unable to scan (data going out).

  `User Tools > System Settings > Interface Settings > Machine IP v4 Address`
- (If using DNS names) Are your DNS servers correct?

  `User Tools > System Settings > Interface Settings > DNS Configuration`
- Can you ping your destinations?

  `User Tools > System Settings > Interface Settings > Ping Command`

**Scan to Folder**:

If you're scanning to Windows 8/Mac OS X 10.7/Windows Server 2012 or later, you'll need to make sure you've got up-to-date firmware for your machine. Print off a configuration page and make sure you've got (at least) the following versions:

`User Tools > Printer Features > Configuration Page`

- System `[2.06 / D1055730L]`
- NIB `[10.63 / D1055745H]`

**Scan to Email**:

This is almost certainly an SSL issue - looking at similar models of that generation it would appear you're on the cusp of support, as the machine is about 3-4 generations old and runs an older version of SSL. I can't find anything conclusive either way as to support unfortunately. See what options you have for SSL in the File Transfer menu. It'll need to be 'On' to connect to Gmail.

`User Tools > System Settings > File Transfer`

Good hunting.